# Python : make DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

When I make dataframe using list, error is occured.
My code is :

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]  
b=['a','b','c','d','e']

df=pd.DataFrame(a,columns=[b])
```

I want this dataframe output :

```
a b c d e  
1 2 3 4 5
```

error code is  `assert(len(items) == len(values))`

what should I do, I hope to solve this ploblem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are strict requirements on the shape and form of the data being passed, you can pass just the data and transpose it to get the initial data as a single row and then overwrite the column names:

```
In [166]:
a=[1,2,3,4,5]  
b=['a','b','c','d','e']
df=pd.DataFrame(data=a).T
df.columns=b
df

Out[166]:
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  2  3  4  5
```

Another method would be to construct a dict and perform a list comprehension on your data elements and makes these a list:

```
In [170]:
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(b,[[x] for x in a])))
df

Out[170]:
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  2  3  4  5
```

inline dict output:

```
In [169]:
dict(zip(b,[[x] for x in a]))

Out[169]:
{'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [3], 'd': [4], 'e': [5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually sending the columns' parameter as - `[['a','b','c','d','e']]` . It needs to be a single list, not a list of lists.

Also, when you send in `a` as the data , you are actually creating 5 rows for 1 column . instead you want to send in `[a]` that would create 1 row and 5 columns.

Try -

```
df=pd.DataFrame([a],columns=b)
```